# use mocha to stub method without any expectation

Tags: ruby, ruby-mocha

I am stubbing a method like this in the setup of one of my tests

```
  def setup
    super
    #blah, blah
    GoogleIdentity.stubs(:new).with(google_identity).returns(google_account)
  end
```

The problem is that not every test will invoke the method and return the object.

In the methods that do not invoke the method, I get this error:

> allowed any number of times, not yet invoked:
>   GoogleIdentity.new()

It seems like mocha is complaining because the method was not invoked.

How can I specify a stub that does not expect it to be calle?

Comment: Did Mocha change this? "A stub is just an expectation of zero or more invocations." http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the implementation of mocha is broken. A method called `stubs` should not care about being called or not. That should be the responsibility of a `mocks` method.

This behavior is one of the things I don't use mocha anymore.

From what I remember when fixing this issue, I used one of the [expectations](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Expectation.html) to handle this scenario like `at_most(1)`.

Comment: And what you use now instead?